# Flutter initialize data into a table at startup

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

I can't seem to find how to write a constant data into a database to be loaded every start up. I want to write a set of data into the specializeArea table where it has an id column and area column as seen here from the DbHelper.dart and specializeModel.dart:

```
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/specializeModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/loginModel.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;

class DbHelper {
  static Database conference;

  static const String DB_Name = 'conference.db';
  static const String Table_conferenceInfo = 'conferenceinfo';
  static const String Table_specializeArea = 'specializearea';
  static const String Table_login = 'login';

  static const String C_UserID = 'id';
  static const String C_Name = 'name';
  static const String C_UName = 'username';
  static const String C_Email = 'email';
  static const String C_Phone = 'phone';
  static const String C_Role = 'role';

  static const String C_Area = 'area';

  static const String C_Password = 'password';
  static const int Version = 1;
  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (conference != null) {
      return conference;
    }
    conference = await initDb();
    return conference;
  }

  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, DB_Name);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: Version, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int intVersion) async {
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $Table_conferenceInfo ("
        " $C_UserID INTEGER, "
        " $C_Name TEXT, "
        " $C_UName TEXT, "
        " $C_Email TEXT,"
        " $C_Password TEXT, "
        " $C_Phone INTEGER, "
        " $C_Role TEXT, "
        " PRIMARY KEY ($C_UserID)"
        ")");
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $Table_specializeArea ("
        " $C_UserID INTEGER, "
        " $C_Area TEXT )");
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $Table_login ("
        " $C_UserID INTEGER, "
        " $C_UName TEXT, "
        " $C_Password TEXT )");
  }

  Future<int> saveData(UserModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.insert(Table_conferenceInfo, user.toMap());
    return res;
  }

  Future<int> saveData1(specializeModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res1 = await dbClient.insert(Table_specializeArea, user.toMap());
    return res1;
  }

  Future<int> saveData2(loginModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res2 = await dbClient.insert(Table_login, user.toMap());
    return res2;
  }

  Future<UserModel> getLoginUser(String userId, String password) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res =
        await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $Table_conferenceInfo WHERE "
            "$C_UName = '$userId' AND "
            "$C_Password = '$password'");

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return UserModel.fromMap(res.first);
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<specializeModel> getSubject(String subject) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res =
        await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $Table_specializeArea WHERE "
            "$C_Area = '$subject'");

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return specializeModel.fromMap(res.first);
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<int> updateUser(UserModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.update(Table_conferenceInfo, user.toMap(),
        where: '$C_UserID = ?', whereArgs: [user.user_id]);
    return res;
  }

  Future<int> deleteUser(String user_id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.delete(Table_conferenceInfo,
        where: '$C_UserID = ?', whereArgs: [user_id]);
    return res;
  }
}
```

```
class specializeModel {
  String user_id;
  String user_area;

  specializeModel(this.user_id, this.user_area);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': user_id,
      'user_area': user_area,
    };
    return map;
  }

  specializeModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    user_id = map['id'];
    user_area = map['user_area'];
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'specializeModel{id: $user_id, user_area: $user_area}';
  }
}
```

The data I want to load is around 5 sets.

Here is the main page of the app, HomeForm.dart:

```
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/specializeModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/comHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/genTextFormField.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/DatabaseHandler/DbHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Screens/LoginForm.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomeForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeFormState createState() => _HomeFormState();
}

class _HomeFormState extends State<HomeForm> {
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Future<SharedPreferences> _pref = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  DbHelper dbHelper;
  final _conUserId = TextEditingController();
  final _conName = TextEditingController();
  final _conDelUserId = TextEditingController();
  final _conUserName = TextEditingController();
  final _conEmail = TextEditingController();
  final _conPassword = TextEditingController();
  final _conCPhone = TextEditingController();
  final _conRole = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserData();

    dbHelper = DbHelper();
  }

  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;

    setState(() {
      _conUserId.text = sp.getString("id");
      _conDelUserId.text = sp.getString("id");
      _conName.text = sp.getString("name");
      _conUserName.text = sp.getString("username");
      _conEmail.text = sp.getString("email");
      _conPassword.text = sp.getString("password");
      _conCPhone.text = sp.getString("phone");
      _conRole.text = sp.getString("role");
    });
  }

  update() async {
    String uid = _conUserId.text;
    String Name = _conName.text;
    String uname = _conUserName.text;
    String email = _conEmail.text;
    String passwd = _conPassword.text;
    String phone = _conCPhone.text;
    String role = _conRole.text;

    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      UserModel user = UserModel(uid, Name, uname, email, passwd, phone, role);
      await dbHelper.updateUser(user).then((value) {
        if (value == 1) {
          alertDialog(context, "Successfully Updated");

          updateSP(user, true).whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginForm()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          });
        } else {
          alertDialog(context, "Error Update");
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
        alertDialog(context, "Error");
      });
    }
  }

  delete() async {
    String delUserID = _conDelUserId.text;

    await dbHelper.deleteUser(delUserID).then((value) {
      if (value == 1) {
        alertDialog(context, "Successfully Deleted");

        updateSP(null, false).whenComplete(() {
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginForm()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Future updateSP(UserModel user, bool add) async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;

    if (add) {
      sp.setString("username", user.user_name);
      sp.setString("Name", user.Name);
      sp.setString("email", user.email);
      sp.setString("password", user.password);
      sp.setString("phone", user.phone);
      sp.setString("role", user.role);
    } else {
      sp.remove('id');
      sp.remove('name');
      sp.remove('username');
      sp.remove('email');
      sp.remove('password');
      sp.remove('phone');
      sp.remove('role');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  //Update
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conUserId,
                      isEnable: false,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hintName: 'User ID'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conName,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hintName: 'Name'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conUserName,
                      icon: Icons.person_outline,
                      inputType: TextInputType.name,
                      hintName: 'Username'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conEmail,
                      icon: Icons.email,
                      inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      hintName: 'Email'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conPassword,
                    icon: Icons.lock,
                    hintName: 'Password',
                    isObscureText: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conCPhone,
                    icon: Icons.phone,
                    hintName: 'Phone',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conRole,
                    icon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                    hintName: 'Role',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Update',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: update,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),

                  //Specialization area

                  //Delete

                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conDelUserId,
                      isEnable: false,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hintName: 'User ID'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Delete',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: delete,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If possible, I would also like to display the data stored as buttons or interactables later but storing them comes first.

Thank you

Comment: What if you add "Insert into.." statement inside _onCreate once you have the tables?

Comment: How would that look like?